# android - Toast text gets cut off

Tags: android, toast

Coming across a weird issue with Toast - I have a few in my app to notify the user when they perform certain actions, and one in particular is having a display issue.  It's fine on the emulator, and it's fine on my co-developer's android phone, but on my phone the second line of text gets cut off.  The toast appears as a single line box and you can see the top of the second line of text that's getting cut off.  Anyone else come across this issue?  Is it just a general bug?  I haven't been able to find the problem with google!

```
msg = getString(R.string.notification_cancel_add);    
Toast.makeText(AddEditActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

and R.string.notification_cancel_add = `<string name="notification_saved_message">Your Notification has been saved.</string>`

Comment: edit to add code - nothing weird about it...

Comment: Does it also cut off the text when you hard-code the `String` into your `Toast`?

Comment: something else to try... will get back to you!

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

It is very weird . But I have solved it by passing the application context.

```
msg = getString(R.string.notification_cancel_add);    
Toast.makeText("pass aplication class context", msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out android localization futures, [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html). Maybe you have to code extra for your phone specifics (display, etc...). Like you said, it works fine with other devices

Comment: But... it's Toast!  I mean it's a totally in-built feature, which is already set to deal with different screen sizes etc - all it does is display a string.  I feel like this has to be a native bug - there's nothing weird about my phone, or my code...

Comment: Going to try messing with the margins and see if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the application context, getContext or MyClass.this
In an Activity, use getApplicationContext()

As said in the developer documentation :

> First, instantiate a Toast object with one of the makeText() methods.
>   This method takes three parameters: the application Context, the text
>   message, and the duration for the toast.

Source : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts